# Change Location for TempDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have by mistake changed  the location for the tempDB files to

> 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'

rather than

> 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf'

I am not able to login into SSMS now and i am also not able to start the SQL services. Also, I have tried logging in using `net start msqsqlserver /f /t3608` but then when i try SQLCMD i get this error  `

> Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can
>   connect at this time

`

Comment: Have you tried **[DAC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx)**?

Answer (score 0):

staring SQL from command line as a service, My instance name is SQL2K8R2 so below would be the command

Net Start MSSQL$SQL2K8R2 /m”SQLCMD”

If you have default instance than it would be "Net Start MSSQLServer /m”SQLCMD”"

Once you have started SQL Service in Single use mode then only SQLCMD application can connect and other connection would get error message.

[image]

```
2013-12-06 09:13:50.08 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf 
     -e E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG 
     -l E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf 
2013-12-06 09:13:50.08 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters: 
     -s "MSSQLSERVER" 
     -m "SQLCMD"

…

2013-12-06 09:13:50.80 spid4s      Warning ****************** 
2013-12-06 09:13:50.80 spid4s      SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.

….

2013-12-06 09:14:32.93 Logon       Error: 18461, Severity: 14, State: 1. 
2013-12-06 09:14:32.93 Logon       Login failed for user ‘Contoso\demouser’. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Comment: SQLCMD does not connect. It gives `Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect` error

Comment: When you start an instance of SQL Server in single-user mode, first stop the SQL Server Agent service. Otherwise, SQL Server Agent might connect first and prevent you from connecting as a second user.

Answer (score 0):

This means that something else is grabbing the single connection.
Your SSMS or some app running with "sa" right.

So, add the -m switch

```
net start msqsqlserver /f /t3608 /m"sqlcmd"
```

Then start SQLCMD as normal

Comment: On running this i get the following error `System Error 1067 has occurred. Process terminated unexpectedly`